# Face ID pop up does not show localized reason

Tags: ios, face-id

I have come across many questions regarding Face ID does not show localized reason in evaluatePolicy and localized reason is only for Touch ID.

Then why do face ID pop up shows localized reason after two wrong attempts?

First,
the pop up only shows Face ID icon

after first wrong attempt,
It shows 
"Face not recongnised\nTry Again"

and after two wrong attempts it shows the localized reason.

I need to know whether it is expected behaviour or a bug?

Comment: If you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and update your questions with the advice given there you should get much better response from the community

Comment: [Anton Tropashko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3544438) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66278363) saying "It is a bug"